# Kotlin Autowired problems - lateinit (obv)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin, lateinit

I'm relatively new to kotlin and I can't get my head around spring autowiring

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property applicationContext has not been initialized
```

I got the above error while running this:

```
@SpringBootTest
internal class MeterResourceAdapterTest () {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var applicationContext: ApplicationContext

@Test
    fun toMeterReadingResourceList() {
        print(applicationContext.applicationName)
.....//I hope my implementation can be ignored
}
```

What is going on here? Why, incidentally, is lateinit required, and WHEN does 'it' get initialised?

Comment: I just tried running a minimal example to reproduce your problem, but it ran fine. If I have to guess, you have some problems with your dependencies that prevent the `applicationContext` from being properly created. You should provide more information - is your app running correctly? Do you have test properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stav Shamir's comment lead me to this resolution.

I can't say for sure what caused this, but it was almost certainly to do with an older version of junit, I had in my pom.xml. When I created a new project, via the initialisier, then copied that pom's contents ( < dependencies/ > ) into my pom; all went smoothly.